# how do you beta a windows phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

How beta windows phone 8.1 app. Might sound like a newbie question but bear with me. I have written and app like quite a few others but this is the first app where I want to support wp8.1 and wp10. The app side loaded on to a wp8.1 or wp10 device works fine as expected.

If put into the Windows store as beta with the necessary emails will install on wp10 devices but refuses to install on wp8.1 devices no matter what.

If I put into the store as normal it fails testing with an ungraceful shutdown that I cannot replicate.

I can't install beta to get the crash dumps to find out what's going on. So now am completely stuck.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to publish a beta version to a specific group of people, then you'll need to select the following option :

> Hide this app and make it available only to the people you specify
>   below, who can download this app on Windows Phone 8.x devices. A
>   promotional code may be used to download this app on Windows 10
>   devices.

Only the people whose email addresses (associated with their Microsoft accounts) that you enter in the box can download your app by using the direct link to its listing. If you want W10 beta testers, then you'll need in addition to generate promotional code and send each promoted link to your W10 beta testers. Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185377.aspx) to learn more about beta publishing on Windows Store.

If you failed to install beta version on WP8.1 devices, I can see two reasons:

1. Email addresses defined in the publisher portal do not match with the one activated on the WP8.1 devices
2. You tried to install the WP8.1 app immediately after defining the list of Email addresses in the publisher portal. In fact you'll to wait couple of hours before beta version becomes available on devices

Comment: Thanks for the comments but I did wait a while and triple checked the email addresses were correct and still no joy. One of the email address was my own

Comment: Can you please detail accurately the different steps you achieved so far ?

Comment: As far as I understand, you create a single app targeting both W10 and WP8.1, right ? So you managed two different app packages, one for WP8.1 and one for W10 and both packages relates to the same app, right ? Then how did you setup the beta submission for W10 ? And for WP8.1 ? Screen captures of the win dev center dasboard would also help us to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. But after a long protracted process I finally got through to Microsoft. (If you do't have paid for MSDN support is damn near impossible to talk to anyone) Turns out there was a problem with my dev account. safe to say the issue is now fixed and apps are downloading/installing again